# Spring bundlor analogs

Tags: java, spring, maven, bundlor

I'm trying to create manifest file for OSGI application using `com.springsource.bundlor` plugin for maven, and have a lot of problems, so Could some one talk me there is analog to spring bundlor or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) which is internally used by [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

Comment: It is interesting, I will try it tomorrow and provide more information about it, Thanks